# Would be this a horrible misuse of Jenkins?

Tags: java, jenkins

I need a Java task to run on a scheduled basis, say daily. It also needs to be occasionally executed on demand, on the click of a button on a web page.

I would like to just compile my business logic into a jar, and drop it somewhere my Jenkins server can reach. And then configure a Jenkins job to execute the main class on a schedule. And to support execution on demand, I can create a Jenkins job (in php or something) to run the main class a single time.

Is this a horrendous misuse? It may seem like a lazy hack to avoid installing Tomcat and consuming a web services call, but it allows me to make changes to the schedule simply by modifying the Jenkins job. And has the significant advantage of avoiding unnecessary overhead, complexity, and maintenance, considering I don't currently have a Tomcat server available.

Comment: I would additionally write a shell (or batch) script that simply runs your program. This script then can be executed with whatever system you like. It could be scheduled with your preferred OS's scheduling mechanism. And of course you can use a simple free-style job in Jenkins. We do so.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. Any advantage of having Jenkins execute a script that runs the program, as opposed to Jenkins directly running the program?

Comment: I would 've jenkins directly execute the jar. That way you can execute it in any OS just by deploying the jar and jenkins client.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is this a horrendous misuse?

Frankly .... who cares.

The issue is whether there are important objective downsides to taking an "expedient" path to achieving what you are trying to achieve.  The only downsides that *might* be relevant are:

- Your Jenkins installation potentially has a bigger footprint (CPU usage, memory usage, disk space usage) than a small web-server.
- There may be hidden costs for people who might need to take over running your systems; e.g. a dependency on a Jenkins installation that they might otherwise not need to maintain.

---

However, don't underestimate the "ewww!" reaction you might get from other people.

Comment: Thanks. I agree, who cares. I just want to be aware of any downsides. The two you mention are not issues; the Jenkins installation already exists, it's in use and maintained. Tomcat would be an additional footprint, so I avoiding a web-server installation as an upside? Any ideas of other potential downsides, or additional advice about defending/justifying this proposition in face of anticipated "ewww" reaction?

Comment: My response to "ewww!" would be "Can you justify the effort of doing it *your* way?"

Answer (score 2):

One slightly more time-consuming but much more advanced solution would be:

> [Spring Batch (Admin UI included)](http://projects.spring.io/spring-batch/)

To be honest we had the exact same idea with Jenkins years ago when we were looking for a quick workaround. In the end we managed to get a bit of a development time allocated for this, so we used Spring batch. It was nice and easy to use via their Admin web app. I suggest checking it out if you have time to do a bit of a coding. This solution worked for us very well because of:

- advanced retry capabilities
- job history
- periodic runs + manual execution option
- capable of resuming failed executions
- capable of retaining job data
- easy to configure for failover

Comment: All those sounds useful (history, failover, etc...). Would it solve the requirement that the job be executed on demand via a button on an existent webpage (does it provide any web service consuming functionality)? If not, how would you recommend manually executing the job via a button on an existent web page?

Comment: The admin page let's you do just that. Check this out: http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch-admin/screenshots.html . It is not really nice (like business user friendly), but works well. You can customize it if you want of course.

Comment: Yeah. Problem is that I would then have to direct users to use the admin page if they want to execute the task (as opposed to just adding a button to the web page they are currently using). Which may be an option, but it would be better if I could do it via button click, which would require some sort of web services consumption/environment (or possibly the Jenkins alternative I suggested). Unless Spring batch provides some web services container functionality?

Comment: The admin also has a JSON interface for remote start. See this (Launching a job):
http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch-admin/reference/json.html